# Sliding card from left side when clicked on button in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In image 1, when the user click on "Apply Coupen", than a window slides from left just above the webpage(see image 2). How to achieve this? And in image 2, we can see a blue transparent color on the webpage just adjacent to the window which slides from left. How to do achieve it?

***Image 1***
[image: Image 1]

***Image 2***
[image: Image 2]

Comment: What you want is style your `<div>` with CSS so that it is hidden, and then, apply new styles upon click to the same `<div>`. Like this https://davidwalsh.name/css-slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it. [Click here and see demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cache-nnbpp?file=/src/App.js:0-413)
If this helps you, please mark as an answer;

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import "./styles.css";
import Sidebar from './component/sidebar'


export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setToggle(pre => !pre)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleToggle} >Click Me</button>
     {toggle && <Sidebar close={() => setToggle(false)} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want the sidebar to smothly slide from left to right when the button is clicked.

Comment: To achieve it you can use framer-motion or react-spring these libraries are related to animation and transition.